# How can I get the music I've put onto my iPhone from CDs onto my new MacBook if theres no CD drive?

Tags: itunes, music

It seems like only the music I purchased in the iTunes store is transferring and I'd like to get the music I've ripped from my CDs onto my new MacBook but there is no CD drive.

Comment: Do you still have your old computer?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for iTunes Match.  It's a $24.99 a year add-on that will allow you to d/l from iTunes anything you ripped to your iTunes library.  I don't think it works tho from just music already on the phone, it has to be ripped to your library using iTunes.

https://www.apple.com/itunes/itunes-match/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free application iFunBox for Mac or Window (http://www.i-funbox.com/) to access the files on your iPhone from your new computer and simply copy the music files to your new computer.